# R Nested foreach %dopar% - issue with inner loop

Tags: r, foreach

I have several spatial entities for which I would like to extract daily climate data time series for several years. To this end, I defined a function that allow to extract for one entity, the corresponding time serie for one year (= a vector of 365 data). Then I used this function in a nested loop %:% with the foreach package with the outter loop for looping on each of my spatial entity and inner loop for looping on each year of the time serie. As output I would like to have a dataframe with in column my spatial entities and in row the climate data time serie. For instance, for 10 entity and 10 years of data, the dimension of my dataframe would be 10 columns and 10*365=3650 rows. The code below works partially since the inner loop (on year) work only for the two first element of my year argument. It is like j=1:2. The inner loop is not running for the other j values.

Could someone help me ? Thank you very much !

```
library(foreach) ; library(doParallel)
library(stringr)
library(raster)

ExtractFromGrid<-function(year=year, grid=grid, liste=liste, fun=fun){
# Mandatory : Shapefile with a colomn "ID_1"
# Targeted year
yeari<-year
# Targeted element in the grid file
gridi<-grid
grid.name<-gridi@data$ID_1
gridi.ext<-extent(gridi)
# Input raster for year j
list.ini<-str_subset(liste, as.character(yeari))
rain<-stack(list.ini)
# Extract value for grid i
gridi.crop<-extract(rain, gridi.ext, fun=fun, layer=1, nl=nlayers(rain))
gridi.v<-as.vector(gridi.crop)
# Format output
output<-data.frame(gridi.v)
colnames(output)<-grid.name
return(output)
}

setwd("myPath")
# Grid to extract
grid.oug<-shapefile("myPath\\BASED_GRID_OUGANDA")

# Rainfall CHRIPS raster
liste.rainfall<-list.files(path=".", pattern="OUG",full.names = TRUE)

year<-seq(1989,2016)

no_cores <- detectCores() - 2
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

#start time
strt<-Sys.time()

outtotal<- foreach(i= 1:length(grid.oug), .packages=c("raster", "stringr"), .combine='cbind') %:%
foreach(j=1:length(year), packages=c("raster", "stringr"), .combine='rbind') %dopar% {
ExtractFromGrid(year=year[j], grid=grid.oug[i,], liste=liste.rainfall, fun='mean')
}

print(Sys.time()-strt)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example including some small data that we can use.

Comment: I provide at this link [https://drive.google.com/open?id=13J6BiRf-hK5Ys_1ApGcsqHaEnONkXJ9N] a sample of my data, including 4 spatial entities in the shapefile and 3 years of climatic data.

Comment: I can't open your link. Also please try to make it directly usable from your code.